# python3 NameError variable not defined

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

I am getting below error
`name i is not defined at line i += 1`
I tried putting at class Solution level. Getting same error

```
class Solution:
    def kthSmallest(self, root: TreeNode, k: int) -> int:
        i = 0
        def inOrder(root):
            global i
            if root == None:
                return
            inOrder(root.left)
            i += 1
            if i == k:
                return
            inOrder(root.right)

        inOrder(root)
        return i
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no global `i`. The variable you want is in the *non-local* enclosing scope.

```
class Solution:
    def kthSmallest(self, root: TreeNode, k: int) -> int:
        i = 0
        def inOrder(root):
            nonlocal i
            if root == None:
                return
            inOrder(root.left)
            i += 1
            if i == k:
                return
            inOrder(root.right)

        inOrder(root)
        return i
```

Answer (score 0):

The scopes of `kthSmallest` and `inOrder` are different. 
Without specifying `i` as a global variable in `kthSmallest`, `i` won't be known inside `inOrder`.

**Nested functions scopes**

For nested functions, you need to declare your global variable in the parent function scope as well.

```py
    class Solution:

        def kthSmallest(self, root: TreeNode, k: int) -> int:
            global i
            i = 0

            def inOrder(root):
                global i
                if root is None:
                    return
                inOrder(root.left)
                i += 1
                if i == k:
                    return
                inOrder(root.right)

            inOrder(root)
            return i
```

**Remark 1**

It looks like you are using a class in your example. You could also have done the following:

```py
    class Solution:
        self.i = 0
        def kthSmallest(self, root: TreeNode, k: int) -> int:
            self.i = 0 

            def inOrder(root):
                if root is None:
                    return
                inOrder(root.left)
                self.i += 1
                if self.i == k:
                    return
                inOrder(root.right)

            inOrder(root)
            return i
```